# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - store values using findelements into the array

Tags: java, selenium

I have findelement statement which selected many values :

```
 String cmpName = Login.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.Name")).getText();
```

How can I store all this values into the array?

So, I need something like this:

```
 for (int a = 0; a<computerAmnt.size(); a++){

        iconCmpArr.get(i).add(cmpName);

        System.out.println("Test : " + iconCmpArr.get(i));
    }
```

But I don't know how to use findelement in this case in FOR statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the selenium [docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) for findElement method it states the return as

```
WebElement findElement(By by)
Returns:
    The first matching element on the current page
```

This shows that it returns only one element (the first element).
So if your locator returns many elements use [findElements](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) (note the 's') which returns a List of WebElements

```
java.util.List<WebElement> findElements(By by)
Returns:
    A list of all WebElements, or an empty list if nothing matches
```

The list can then be traversed using for loop. Hope this helps.